# A map contains another Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, set

I want to create a Map which is contains another map.If there is no special key in inner Map, I want to create that key with value= 1, otherwise increment its value.
 I wrote **this code** :

```
Map <String, Map <String,Double>> ingMap= new HashMap<>();
Map <String,Double> k= new HashMap<>();
k.put("Class1", 1.0);
ingMap.put("A", k);
k.put("Class2", 1.0);
ingMap.put("A", k);
k.put("Class1", 1.0);
ingMap.put("B", k);
k.put("Class2", 1.0);
ingMap.put("B", k);
k = ingMap.get("A");
if (k.containsKey("Class3")) {            
    k.put("Class3", k.get(k)+1);
    ingMap.put("A", k );
}
else{                        
    k.put("Class3", 1.0);
    ingMap.put("A",k );                       
 }
 System.out.println("\n" + ingMap);
```

The result is:

```
{A={Class1=1.0, Class2=1.0, Class3=1.0}, B={Class1=1.0, Class2=1.0, **Class3=1.0}**}
```

But really I wanted :

```
{A={Class1=1.0, Class2=1.0, Class3=1.0}, B={Class1=1.0, Class2=1.0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the same inner map `k` in all the values of the outer map.
You need to create a new inner map instance for each outer map key :

```
Map <String,Double> k= new HashMap<>();
k.put("Class1", 1.0);
k.put("Class2", 1.0);
ingMap.put("A", k);

k= new HashMap<>();
k.put("Class1", 1.0);
k.put("Class2", 1.0);
ingMap.put("B", k);
```

And there's no need to put the same value with the same key twice, as it does nothing.

And the code for updating the inner map should be like this :

```
k = ingMap.get("A");
if (k != null) {
    if (k.containsKey("Class3")) {            
        k.put("Class3", k.get("Class3")+1);
    }
    else {                        
        k.put("Class3", 1.0);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks, It works well. However I really thankful if you can explain effect of these lines: k= new HashMap<>();  and  your second code (if (k != null) ...)

Comment: @Masoud You need to create a new instance of the inner map for each key of the outer map, otherwise, ingMap.get("A") and ingMap.get("B") would return the exact same inner map. As for the latter code, when you fetch a value from the map by key, you should check that the returned value is not null. If an inner map already exists for the "A" key, there is no need to put("A",k) again. You just need to modify the inner map of "A".